# How can CSS/JavaScript create a push down effect on a click/mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, css, button, user-interface, css-animations

When you log into stackoverflow.com via gmail or similar., when you click on the gmail button, it appears to be pushed down.

How do you achieve this effect?

I know how to use CSS3 to make something look raised using a drop shadow.  But how do you make it appear to move down.

It appears they are removing the shadow while at the same time shifting the div to the previous place of the shadow.

However I'd prefer a more continuous effect.  I only need this to work in modern browsers.

Also, they are moving on a hover event, I need it on a click event.

Comment: Did you think about using a <button>? Did you view the source of the page?

Comment: ...in my particular case nope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the CSS for the buttons. No JS is required.

```
.login-page .openid_large_btn {

    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #ddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #ddd;
}

.login-page .openid_large_btn:hover {

    margin: 4px 0px 0px 6px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

element.style {

    background: #fff url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/openid/openid-logos.png?v=8);
    background-position: -1px -1px;
}
```

As observed above,

margin-top and left is increased, while the other sides are set to 0, from 3px:

```
margin: 4px 0px 0px 6px;
```

border is darkened:

```
border: 2px solid #999;
```

shadows are removed:

```
box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: I want to do it on a click not a hover, is it possible to modify?...i.e. `: click`

Comment: @pure_code change `.openid_large_btn:hover` to `.openid_large_btn:active` if you want on click.

Comment: ....thanks...what about making it continuous, using css3 animations - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: that was in the original question - `However I'd prefer a more continuous effect.`

Answer (score 2):

To add transitions, add this:

```
.login-page .openid_large_btn {

    -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
```